# Python Error : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

When I run my Python file I get the following error:

```
config = open('config.json', 'r')
config_data = json.load(config_file)
```

---

This is my json file:

```
{
 "temp_unit": "celsius"
}
```

---

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/Documents/Nouvale/main.py", line 90, in <module>
    App.read_config()
  File "/home/paul/Documents/Nouvale/main.py", line 35, in read_config
    config_data = json.load(config_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

---

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I am using Zorin 16.1 Pro, Python 3.8.10 & Pip 20.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

## Soloution

---

To fix the error I added an encoding parameter.

---

```
config = open('config.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
config_data = json.load(config)
```